# Invertibility of matrices with determinant $> 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am looking for an intuitive clear explanation on why matrices with determinant $> 1$ (in absolute value) are invertible. Since every "unit of volume" on the source space is being inflated on the destination space, this is not a trivial conjecture.

(Not a rigorous proof but rather an intuitive explanation)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, every matrix with nonzero determinant is invertible

Comment: You can see how volumes can be inflated. Can you see how they can be deflated?

Comment: The inverse of a matrix is given as $A^{-1}=\frac{\text{adj} (A)}{\det (A)}$, which is true for every non singular $A$

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes. I know. But only the > 1, is harder to explain, since in that case a unit a volume is being projected to a bigger volume. How can you invert that ?

Comment: Note that if $|\det(A)|>1$, then $|\det(A^{-1})|<1$.  Therefore, if you can explain the case where the magnitude of the determinant is less than one, then by thinking backwards, we can get the case where the magnitude of the determinant is greater than one.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you.